# What is Balbiani's vitelline body function?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, reproduction, development

I tried searching on Google Scholar but I found little to no information about this Balbiani's vitelline body.

I don't even know why it is called vitelline...I've been taught that it can be seen under the electron microscope, is perinuclear, made of mitochondria and *lamelle anulatae* (I don't know what these are) and you can see it only in primordial follicles.

I initially thought it was involved in protein synthesis, but primordial follicles should be biologically quiescent until they 'wake up' and begin folliculogenesis.

Comment: Did you read [this section in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granule_(cell_biology)#Germline_granules)?

Comment: No, I didn't.I'm reading it now for the first time.So this vitelline body silences transposons?

Comment: We can close this question as solved.